# Matplotlib: plots two extra lines on my graph?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I have a csv file which has two sets of data. Basically:

```
    for row in reader:
    ###I have some other code but here's the stuff that applies to the question###

        disorder_long = sequence_analysis(looped_region.upper(), mode = 'long')
        disorder_short = sequence_analysis(looped_region.upper(), mode = 'short')

        length = len(list(disorder_short))
        #print length

        xmin = 1
        xmax_long = length
        ymin = 0
        ymax_long = max(disorder_long)
        ymax_short = max(disorder_short)

        y_limit = max([ymax_long, ymax_short])
        #print y_limit

        while True:
            try:
                newfig = str(raw_input('Name the graph to be created: '))
                break #break out of loop
            except ValueError:
                print("error")
                continue #return to start of loop

        plt.figure           

        #data
        x_series = np.array(range(1,length+1))
        # print "x series: "
        # print x_series
        # print len(x_series)
        y_series1 = np.array(disorder_long)
        y_series2 = np.array(disorder_short)
        # print y_series1, y_series2

        #plot data
        plt.plot(x_series, y_series1, label=uniprot_id+' long')
        plt.plot(x_series, y_series2, label=uniprot_id+' short')

        #add limits to the x and y axis
        plt.xlim(xmin, xmax_long)
        plt.ylim(ymin, 1)

        #create legend
        plt.legend(loc="upper left")

        #save figure to png
        plt.savefig(newfig)`
```

Returns me two graphs, one of which is perfectly fine (its the first set of data) but the other has two extra lines plotted and I have no idea where they came from. Second graph has two extra lines, the top two are extraneous.[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Just at a cursory glance, the second graph, top two lines, appear to be the same as the lines in the first. I'm not the best with matplotlib but I do see that the line

```
plt.figure
```

doesn't specify it needs to make a new one. You should use `plt.figure(1)` and `plt.figure(2)` to specify they are different figures

Comment: Is there a way for me to create a new figure without having to do `plt.figure(number)`? Like with files you can just use w to create a new file as opposed to a for appending. I'd like not to append to my graph.

Comment: Hold on I figured it out... `plt.clf()`

Comment: You need to _call_ `plt.figure()` to get a new figure, as it is you are just having python evaluate that the function `figure` exists in the pyplot name space

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.clf()
```

works to create new plots without appending to the existing one.